# partitioned os lost

Tags: boot, partitioning, updates, wubi

I have a computer with dual boot Windows and Ubuntu. I decided to download updates in Ubuntu but in the middle my computer froze so I had to do a hard reset. When I started the computer again I got an error message with an **OK** option. I clicked it and when I start the computer now all I get is this error message on start. How can I solve my problem?

```
window failed to start.  A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  To fix the problem:

1.  Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer (I don't have one)
2. ...
3. ...
...
File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
Status: 0xc000000f
Info:  the selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.
```

---

Yes, it was a dual boot.  The original operating system was W. Vista.  Now it's W.7 and Ubuntu.  However, in attempting again to re-install the Ubuntu now it looks like I've lost the partition altogether.  However, it is supposed to give me 3 options to install, with the first being to install "alongside".  But this option isn't there.

I don't know which Ubuntu version was first installed, but looking at the dates of when the programs were written, and knowing when my son-in-law installed it, it should be 13.04 which is the one I'm trying to install.

As to personal files, I do have files on this computer now.  I've been using it for

1. learning or installing this Ubuntu situation, and
2. transferring audio files into compatible CD formats, under Win7.
   I am thinking of just giving up on this idea.  It looks to me like Ubuntu is just a desktop (without root directory access) with OpenOffice Suite and I have OO as well as root directory access.

Oh yeah, I don't care for Win7.  I like Win XP best.

BTW, I am unable to put properties into the audio .wav file.  I downloaded Media Monkey, because forum folks said this would resolve the problem.  But after entering all the information into MM I checked the actual file and the info was not there.  After MM asked me if I wanted the information burned onto the CD with the file, it wasn't (actually it asked if I wanted the text files burned for devices that would read that info, such as ipods.  I would think my computer would qualify and the info isn't there.)  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Need to know the error message to better help solve your problem.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? What Ubuntu version do you have? Did you install Ubuntu via Wubi?

Comment: T Hackenberg - please login with your registered account.  Then click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request that your unregistered account is merged.  Once done, you'll be able to edit your question  with further details.  Thanks.

Comment: @T_Hackenberg Do you have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows?If yes then tell me that Windows is on UEFI or BIOS? and tell me that which PC OR Laptop you are using so I can Help you!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your MBR is damaged. You can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair) to fix it, read carefully the whole article before you start. I recommend that you make a boot-repair cd or usb after you download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home)

Answer (score -1):

I am posting this as a second answer because it is a very different reply.

I hat this thought about your situation.
If your computer had windows installed by a OEM (Asus, Dell, etc) you might
have a Factory Reset option on it.
Usually manufacturers provide that option when they do not give you a hard copy
of Windows to reinstall from.

Most computers and laptops use either the F9, F11 or F12 key to start a 
reinstall to the original factory image.

Try booting up and keep tapping one of those keys until it either works or not.
Start with the F9. 
Turn on your computer and start tapping.
Good luck!

Comment: How will this solve the Ubuntu problem? What about the OP files on the computer?

Comment: The OP was just given the computer and he is trying to use it but can't. He cannot have any personal files on it if he hasn't used it yet!!